# parent function not invoked when called from child component in reactjs typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I am developing a small web app in react using typescript in visual studio. I have a parent and a child component and i want to invoke the parent component's function from the child. I have written the following code but it seems that i am doing something wrong

Parent.tsx

```
export class Parent extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}>{
constructor() {
    super()
    this.deleteFunction = this.deleteFunction.bind(this);
}

deleteFunction(){
console.log('delete called from parent');
}

public render() {
    return (
            <div>
                 <Child deleteFunction={this.deleteFunction.bind(this)} />
            </div>
   )
}
```

Child.tsx

```
class ChildProps{
deleteFunction: any;
}


export class Child extends React.Component<ChildProps, {}> {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.handledeletebutton = this.handledeletebutton.bind(this);
}

handledeletebutton(){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('delete called from child');
   this.props.deleteFunction;
}

render(
    <div>
        < a href='#' onClick={this.handledeletebutton}>Delete</a>
   </div>
)
}
```

I can see the log of child in my console but i cannot see the log of parent. It seems to be working with .jsx files but i have no idea why it isn't in  typescript. Also i cannot see any error in console. I am very new to typescript so maybe i have made a silly mistake. Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple. I just had to use proper syntax. As deleteFunction is a function, i had to use deleteFunction() in my child component. So the handledeletebutton() would be as follows

```
handledeletebutton(){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('delete called from child');
    this.props.deleteFunction();<= Use as a function
 }
```